Convergence to stationary distribution of a lazy random walk vs random walk on an undirected graph.
Given a small-world type undirected graph, I'm trying to understand if a lazy random walk (I.e. with .5 probability of staying on the vertex at each step) would tend to converge to the stationary distribution faster or slower than a regular random walk? Any insight as to why one or the other may be the case would be appreciated.
The context of this question is the following: in designing an algorithm to measure probability "flows" in the intermediate time steps as the random walks "propagate" through the graph, it's not clear to me whether a more rapid convergence is better or worse, as at the stationary distribution, the flows have become zero.

A lazy random walk is sometimes necessary in order to ever achieve convergence. This comes up if your graph is bipartite. In that case, the non-lazy random walk will never converge, because it will always alternate between the two sides of the bipartition. The distribution will be completely different depending on whether you have taken an even or odd number of steps, and it will never converge to a stationary distribution. By contrast, after the first step, the lazy random walk is equally likely to be on either side of the bipartition, and so it will be able to converge.
Even if the graph is not bipartite, it could be nearly bipartite; maybe it has a few edges violating a near-bipartition. Then the non-lazy random walk will still have an oscillating effect after $n$ steps depending on whether $n$ is even or odd, and the lazy random walk will not have this effect at all. This is the main reason to pick the lazy random walk.

In a scenario where periodic effects are negligible, and the non-lazy random walk more or less smoothly gets closer and closer to the stationary distribution the longer you go, the lazy random walk will do the same - but twice as slowly.
To see this, let the vector $\pi^{(n)}$ be the probability distribution in the non-lazy random walk after $n$ steps. (We expect that $\pi^{(n)} \to \pi$ as $n \to \infty$, where $\pi$ is the stationary distribution.)
Then the probability distribution in the lazy random walk after $n$ steps is given by
$$
   \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom nk}{2^n} \pi^{(k)}.
$$
The idea here is that there is a $\binom nk/2^n$ probability that the lazy random walk will decide to take $k$ actual steps, and be lazy $n-k$ times, over the course of $n$ steps. If it takes $k$ actual steps, then $\pi^{(k)}$ is the probability distribution of where it might end up.
For large $n$, the weights $\binom nk/2^n$ are going to be large when $k \approx n/2$; specifically, for any constant $C>0$, they are proportional to $1/\sqrt n$ when $k \in [n/2 - C\sqrt n, n/2 + C\sqrt n]$, and the sum of all weights outside this range can be made arbitrarily small by increasing $C$. Or to put it differently: for large $n$, the random walk is almost certain to take between $n/2-C\sqrt n$ and $n/2 + C\sqrt n$ actual steps.
So we can think of the probability distribution in the lazy random walk as being essentially a weighted average of $\pi^{(k)}$ for $k \in [n/2 - C\sqrt n, n/2 + C\sqrt n]$. By time $n$, it has converged about as much to the stationary distribution as the non-lazy random walk had already converged by time $n/2$ or so.
However, the advantage of the lazy random walk is that it is not just picking up on $\pi^{(n/2)}$ but that it is an average of many $\pi^{(k)}$ with $k$ near $n/2$. This, again, smooths out any periodic effects in the convergence.
